# Merge two videos in file format of mp4 using nodejs

Tags: node.js, amazon-s3, serverless, aws-serverless, fluent-ffmpeg

I want to merge two or more videos which is stored s3 into a single video in nodejs.I tried to implement using fluent-ffmpeg , I am getting an error that "Cannot find ffprobe".

Answer (score 0):

this might help

```
const ffmpegPath = require('@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg').path;
const ffmpeg = require('fluent-ffmpeg');
ffmpeg.setFfmpegPath(ffmpegPath);
```